# Android Logcat not showing timestamp, other info on every line

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat

Either Android Studio, or Logcat is removing time, process info, tag and log priority information from some lines of the logcat output.  Is there any way to get around this?

Here is an example:

```
11-27 11:28:05.470 7399-7399/com.myapp D/tag: Log statement 1
11-27 11:28:05.471 7399-7399/com.myapp D/tag: Log statement 2
11-27 11:28:05.509 7399-7399/com.myapp D/tag: Log statement 3
    Log statement 4
11-27 11:28:11.735 7399-7474/com.myapp D/tag: Log statement 5
    Log statement 6
11-27 11:28:11.737 7399-7474/com.myapp D/tag: Log statement 7
```

It would be great to just have them all do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I find the Android Studio debugging console to be listlessly frustrating, and I actually use an external application for monitoring my logcat. mLogcat is my preferred option, but there are others available.

If you wish to use specifically the Android Studio debugging tools, make certain your IDE is up to date.

You can also try killing and re-establishing the connection with your device by running the following line in a command prompt:

```
adb kill-server
```

You'll need to reconnect your device (Either with USB or through your network). ADB can have some issues at times, particularly if you have multiple devices connected.